# linking email subsciptions to WordPress blogs to CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress

I am adding a blog to the WordPress site on which I am running CiviCRM. I want to include an email subscription to the blog. Ideally I'd like to link this subscription to the CiviCRM contact (for example: so that I can send subscribers extra emails or that I can send invitations to the blog to non subscribing members)

I have found a couple of solutions to the blog subscription (JetPack and Mailchimp) but neither link with the WordPress users or CiviCRM contacts.

I may well be able to use the Mailchimp CivCRM Integration plugin to link it all up, but I'd still rather avoid using Mailchimp because of the cost if the blog really takes off and I don't need any of the other functionality.

[How to automatically create mailings from an RSS feed](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25428/how-to-automatically-create-mailings-from-an-rss-feed) looks to have some of the functionality, but would still need development beyond my capabilities and I'm not sure its active.

Has anyone found any good solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would work with Wordpress but you could do something like: https://civicrm.org/extensions/content-tokens  to pull in the content combined with 
https://civicrm.org/extensions/scheduled-communication to automatically schedule the mailings.